# .NET: Which Exception to Throw When Required Property is Not Set?

Tags: .net, exception, dependency-injection

Assume I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar RequiredProperty { get; set;}

    public void Baz()
    {
        if (this.RequiredProperty == null)
        {
            // Which exception should I throw?
        }
    }
}
```

My solution has a class that is designed to be reused without having to pass a lot of arguments to the `Bar` method over and over again. So, what should I throw when `Bar` isn't initialized to a non-null value?

**More Information**
I'm essentially rolling my own code parser and formatter. Call it an object lesson. One of the classes is an `HtmlCodeFormatter` that has the following properties (in honor of Dependency Injection):

```
public IFormatter Formatter { get; set; }
public IParser Parsre { get; set; }
```

This allows me to write any number of language-specific parsers and formatters. For example, I have a `CSharpParser` and a `JavascriptParser`. I also have an `HtmlCodeFormatter`, and there are plans for another (of dubious utility).

The idea is that you can instantiate the `HtmlFormatter` using an object initializer, like this:

```
var formatter = new HtmlCodeFormatter()
    {
        Parser = new CSharpParser();
        Formatter = new HtmlCodeFormatter();
    };
formatter.Format("Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, world!\"));
```

When `HtmlCodeFormatter.Format` is invoked, it needs to be able to verify that both a parser and a formatter have been provided. That's no problem, really, but I'm kind of stumped about which exception to throw. I'm leaning towards `InvalidOperationException`, but I'm not entirely certain that's the best choice.

Comment: Why don't you pass them in in the constructor? Are there that many properties that passing them to the constructor becomes hard to read?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Good question. It's a matter of taste in this case. Personally, I find object initializers to be far more readable.

Comment: Named parameters in C# 4 can add a lot to readability.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would throw a [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx). The MSDN definition is:

> The exception that is thrown when a
>   method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

**However**, i recommend using constructor injection instead of setter injection. This makes sure you has valid parsers and formatters. If null is passed in the constructor, throw a [ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx).

Comment: Jon Skeet agrees. I'm sold. (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903105/which-exception-to-throw-when-a-method-try-to-use-a-field-that-can-be-null).

Comment: Spot on then, wonderful!

Answer (score 7):

By using **Propery Injection** you are implicitly telling the compiler, fellow developers as well as DI Containers that the **dependency is optional**. This is because **no-one forces you to assign a property value**.

If the dependency is truly required, you should refactor to **Constructor Injection**. This will effectively make the dependency required:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        if (bar == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");
        }

        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Bar RequiredProperty
    {
        get { return this.bar; }
    }

    public void Baz()
    {
        // this.bar is now GUARANTEED to be initialized,
        // so no checks are required
    }
}
```

Notice that the constructor Guard Clause (throwing an ArgumentNullException) effectively **protects the invariants** of the class, which is further strengthened by the `readonly` keyword.

With the dependency part of the class' invariants, you no long have any **temporal coupling** and you can now implement all members without worrying whether the dependency has been assigned or not.

Comment: I can definitely see your point, but I was under the impression that it's A Very Bad Idea™ to throw exceptions in a constructor, and that it was to be avoided At All Costs™.

Comment: Not at all. The principle is called Fail Fast. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: You know, I don't really know. There *is* the nagging chance that I'll get a TypeInitializationFailed exception, which might mask the real problem. But I *am* a fan of fail fast, so I've fixed my code with your guidance in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw `NotInitializedException`.

Comment: What namespace is NotInitializedException in?